# vscode - remote ssh connection - can I specify the git path?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am connecting up to my server via ssh successfully, but the default git that is installed is an older version (1.8.x).  I do have a newer version that I use but it is not in the default location.

My .bashrc adds the location to my path, so when I log in, I use the newer version by default.

**How can I tell vscode which one to use?**  My settings.json file on my Windows workstation will let me specify it on the windows box, but I do not see how I can specify it for my remote connection (theoretically it could be different for each remote connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect to the remote ssh server.
2. Go to settings UI.
3. Select the remote tab and search for `git.path`
   [image]

4. Now click `Edit in settings.json`.

Then you can set the path:

```
{
    "git.path": "/<path to>/git"
}
```